# Which account to use while testing in-app purchase?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, ios4, in-app-purchase

I am implementing in-app purchase. Basically, I am making a trial app. So I am a little bit confused and maybe forgetting a step in implementation. While I am testing the app on my device, it's asking for my AppleID password.

Do I need to create new AppleID password? Which ID and password do I need to provide it?

Comment: I'm not sure, but can you not make Apple test accounts for this?

Comment: But I don't find any option !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create an apple test user for this. Log into http://itunesconnect.apple.com. Click "Manage Users" and then "Test User".